# Python program to rotate a line not working

Tags: python, math, vector, 3d, trigonometry

I am trying to figure out direction vectors of the `arrowheads` of an arrow. Basically I'm given a normalized direction vector `(u,v,w)` and I need the normalized direction vectors of the its two arrow heads which make a 15 degree angle.

My plan is to first start off with a simple normalized vector `(0,0,1)`. The direction vectors of its arrow heads are `(-sin(15), 0, -cos(15))` and `(sin(15), 0, -cos(15))`, and then rotate `(0,0,1)` so its parallel to the given `(u,v,w)`. I do this by projecting `(u,v,w)` on its x-axis, and getting its angle relative to `(0,0,1)`, then projecting on the y-axis, and getting its angle relative to `(0,0,1)`, then I use the 3d rotation matrices to use those found angles to rotate the arrow head direction vector.

I have this code below, but its not working properly. Does anyone see whats wrong?

Thanks

```
        ra = 15
        ca = math.cos(ra)
        sa = math.sin(ra)

        px = (0,v,w)
        if u!=1:
            px = [i/float(math.sqrt(v**2 + w**2)) for i in px]

        py = (u,0,w)
        if v!=1:
            py = [i/float(math.sqrt(u**2 + w**2)) for i in py]

        pxangle = math.acos(px[2])
        pyangle = math.acos(py[2])

        cpx = math.cos(pxangle)
        spx = math.sin(pxangle)
        cpy = math.cos(pyangle)
        spy = math.sin(pyangle)

        def rotatefunction(ah):
            xr = (ah[0], -spx*ah[2], cpx*ah[2])
            return (cpy*xr[0]+spy*xr[2], xr[1], -spy*xr[0]+cpy*xr[2]) 

        lah = rotatefunction((-sa, 0, -ca))
        rah = rotatefunction((sa, 0, -ca))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to convert degrees into radians (= degree * (pi / 180)) before passing to math.cos, math.sin, etc.

Suppose the normalized direction vector of the arrow is given by

[image]

The unit vector parallel to the z-axis is given by

[image]

The orthonormal vector perpendicular to both the unit vectors are given by the cross product

[image]

and the angle between the two vector is given by the scalar product

[image]

Basically the rotation is about this u (uhat) axis by angle theta. The corresponding [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is given by

[image]

so this is the matrix you need to multiply the arrowhead vectors with.